# Three.js and Tween.js, chained animation with rotations does not work

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I'm trying to move a cube first towards to the camera, then turn left, and then move forward, to the right side of the screen. I'm building a maze where a turtle will move forward and rotate and I want to use tweenjs for the animations.

A fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/edapx/o6mvg0d5/1/

As you see, the first two animation are executed, but the last one does not move the cube as expected. I'm chaining the animations like this:

```
function testChained(){
    var radians = 90 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD;

    var pos_copy_a = new THREE.Vector3().copy(mesh.position);
    var target_a = pos_copy_a.add(new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 50.0));
    var rotationMatrix_a = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(mesh.rotation.y);
    target_a.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix_a);
    var a = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.position).to(target_a, 900);

    var target_b = {y:mesh.rotation.y + radians};
    var b = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.rotation).to(target_b, 900);

    var pos_copy_c = new THREE.Vector3().copy(mesh.position);
    var target_c = pos_copy_c.add(new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 50.0));
    var rotationMatrix_c = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(mesh.rotation.y);
    target_c.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix_c);
    var c = new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.position).to(target_c, 900);

    a.chain(b);
    b.chain(c);
    a.start();
};
```

Am I using tween.js wrong?

Comment: In the fiddle, you forgot to add `TWEEN.update()` in the `animate()`.

Comment: Sorry, i've forgot to save the fiddle. Now is there and you can see the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is, because you set `target_c` before all animations start. So, `target_c` is the same as `target_a`. When animation c starts, the mesh is at position `0 0 50`, but `target_c` is `0 0 50`, too. So, you need to set `target_c` after animation a has completed. Animation c relies on the "result" of the previous ones, I guess, chaining like isn't that easy.

In jsfiddle, I just just wrapped the instantiation of animation c into the complete callback of animation b to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/327bcLgp/

**EDITED Question**

What I'm looking for it is called is animation with relative values. https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md#relative-values It works when piling up rotations, but mixing rotation and translation is tricky. Here an updated fiddle that still does not works https://jsfiddle.net/edapx/o6mvg0d5/5/

**EDITED Answer**

It's not just a string (`String(distance_a.x)`), you need to prefix it with a plus sign to make it relative: `'+' + distance_a.x;`

And I wouldn't use `mesh.rotation.y` to rotate the vector. That's the same as I described above. When you set set `rotationMatrix_c`, `mesh.rotation.y` will be still `0`. Instead, use fix values.

```
var radians = 90 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD;
...
var rotationMatrix_c = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(radians);
var distance_c = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 50.0);
distance_c.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix_c);
var target_c = {
    x: '+' + distance_c.x,
    y: '+' + distance_c.y,
    z: '+' + distance_c.z
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o6mvg0d5/6/

If you have more rotations, you need to sum up the  radians value, e.g. `radians += 90 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD;`

Comment: I think what I'm looking for it is called "relative value" in the the tween.js guide. https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md

Comment: I see what you mean. But I've a stack of tweens animation saved in an array in my real application (non in the fiddle) and i need to consume them.

Comment: this matrix `var rotationMatrix_c = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(radians);` was intended to get the current rotation of the current y axis rotation of the local mesh. I see that it is wrong, however `new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(radians);` it is not what I want. Regarding the + and - sign, you are right, it is required, but is difficult to keep track of the sign after several rotations. It would be nice to have a method dedicated to relative values (this is how it is called on the tweens docs) for vectors. I will implement a solution without tweenjs, thanks for your help ;)